# Moshi custom qualifier annotation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I am having a problem converting some code to kotlin. The annotation for custom qualifier are ignored.
I define them like this:

```
class ColorAdapter {

    @ToJson
    internal fun toJson(@PassDefinitions.HexColor rgb: Int): String {
        return String.format("#%06x", rgb)
    }

    @FromJson
    @PassDefinitions.HexColor
    internal fun fromJson(rgb: String): Int {
        return Color.parseColor(rgb)
    }
}
```

and trying to use them like this:

```
@HexColor
override var backgroundColor: Int = 0
```

but it just gets ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this syntax:

```kotlin
@field:[HexColor]
override var backgroundColor: Int = 0
```